# Using Tramp mode in Emacs on Windows with keyfile

Tags: emacs, windows-8, ssh-keys, plink, tramp

I'm trying to use Tramp from Emacs on Windows 8, using plink and a putty prikey file. Is this possible? I can configure tramp to use plink successfully, but can't find a bit of information for using a keyfile with Tramp on Windows without using cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Tramp doesn't care about, it's PuTTY's business. Usually you create your keyfile with `PuTTYgen`. Then you let `Pageant` run in the background, that's it. [This page](https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty) seems to be a proper explanation.